# get error while trying to access a list

Tags: c++

I've got a list with a struct:

```
struct structPlacedBets
{
    int betOption = 0;
    int betValue = 0;
    int betChips = 0;
    int player = 1;
}
```

the list:

```
list <structPlacedBets> placedBets;
```

when writing to the list, there is no problem. I fill a temporary variable with the data, and then I handover the temporary variable to the list.

```
placedBets.push_back (tempPlacedBets);
```

Everything fine.

I also can access the list in the main function, everything good.

But, I wanted to handover the memory adress from the list to a function, and then output everything from the list. In the moment where I try to access the data, my program crashes.

Here is the code:

```
struct structPlacedBets
{
    int betOption = 0;
    int  betValue = 0;
    int betChips = 0;
    int player = 1;
}

list <structPlacedBets> placedBets;
structPlacedBets tempPlacedBets;   //temporary variable for filling the list
.
.
.
placedBets.push_back (tempPlacedBets);
.
.
.
void outputList(list <structPlacedBets> &tempList)
{
    list <structPlacedBets>::iterator Iterator;

    for (Iterator == tempList.begin(); Iterator != tempList.end(); Iterator++)
    {
        cout << Iterator->betOption;    //here the program crashes
    }
}


int main()

    outputList(placedBets);

return 0;
```

When accessing the list directly in the main, without another function, everything is fine.

Works well:

```
int main()
    list <structPlacedBets>::iterator Iterator;

    for (Iterator = placedBets.begin(); Iterator != placedBets.end(); Iterator++)
    {
        cout << (*Iterator).betOption << endl;
        cout << (*Iterator).betValue << endl;
        cout << (*Iterator).betChips << endl;
        cout << (*Iterator).player << endl;
    }
```

Hope, anybody knows the problem and the answer.
Thank you.

Comment: You probably didn't mean to say this: `Iterator == tempList.begin()`

Comment: Recommendation for avoiding the typo pointed out by AndyG: use `auto` to create iterators.

Comment: _"I wanted to handover the memory adress from the list to a function"_ Actually it's a reference

Comment: @KyleStrand: That can cause its own problems. Best to simply read your code. Also I'd be astounded if the compiler didn't warn on this

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Every feature in C++ can "cause its own problems," and your recommendation to "simply read your code" is [blaming the programmer](https://eev.ee/blog/2016/12/01/lets-stop-copying-c/#blaming-the-programmer). (It took me several re-reads to catch the erroneous `==`, *even after seeing it pointed out*!)

Comment: @KyleStrand: Well, it's the programmer's fault, so yes I will blame the programmer.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Did you click on the link? It explains why that's a dangerous/harmful mindset.

Comment: @KyleStrand: For a language designer, yes; for a troubleshooter, no. It is not related to my comment. It's about how to design a good language, not about finding a solution to the OP's problem. Meanwhile, recommending `auto` on the basis of this problem alone without at least discussing its downsides, painting it as a universal solution, is just irresponsible.

Comment: Why use `auto` when a  range-based `for` would do? If you have one, you have the other.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree that that would be even better.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Okay, sure, that blog post is about language design. But from a language use perspective, it's important to use the feature-set that will make it *harder* to make dangerous mistakes and *easier* for the compiler to help. I specifically recommended `auto` for creating *iterators*, and I would argue that using `auto` to capture the return values from `.begin()`, `.end()`, etc is actually somewhat harder to screw up than the method the OP has chosen, and much harder to screw up than "simply read[ing] your code."

Comment: Damn, what a stupid mistake. Compiler didn't give warning. I will better look for my code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, you have a typo:

```
for (Iterator == tempList.begin(); Iterator != tempList.end(); Iterator++)
//            ^^
```

`Iterator` was never initialised to anything! Comparing it, then dereferencing it (and, if you got that far, incrementing and comparing it again) all has *undefined behaviour*.

In the second example you correctly wrote `=`.

Pay closer attention to your code, and turn on your compiler's warnings.

Comment: Sadly I can't get any flavour of gcc to emit a warning for that, even with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`. Visual Studio 2015 misses it as well. Clang nails it, though.

Comment: Damn, what a stupid mistake. Compiler didn't give warning, then I had seen it by myself. Thanks for looking. Thanks for help